# How to add new state to user story azure devops

Tags: user-stories, pm-software, task-management

When I try to add new `completed state` to `user story` or `task` in `inherited process` of my `azure devops project`, I get the following **error** :

> VS403093: Team Services currently does not support changes to
>   'Completed' category. Choose a different category.

I have looked all over the web and it seems like this is the desired behaviour as mentioned in this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/237062/vs403093-team-services-currently-does-not-support.html), which I think is very weird.

Are there any workarounds?

I want to create a `Done` state for my work items, and I think that it's dumb to keep only the `closed` state for all completed work items since `Completed` fits better with `tickets` not with `user stories` in my sense...

As mentioned below, I could modify all the states except for completed
[image: VS403093]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Team Services currently does not support changes to 'Completed' category.

That's not a bug, it is working as designed.

You can [read more about it here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/237062/vs403093-team-services-currently-does-not-support.html).